# Polymer: Dynamically change the stylesheet

Tags: polymer, stylesheet

I would like to apply some stylesheets dynamically using Polymer. The scenario is like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="themes/red.styles.html" />
<link rel="import" href="themes/indigo.styles.html" />

<dom-module>
    <style include="indigo-styles">
    <template>
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <button on-click="_toggleStylesheet"></button>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    _toggleStylesheet: function () {
      // remove indigo-styles and apply red-styles and so on
    }
  })
</script>
```

Does anyone know how can this be achieved in Polymer?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`this.updateStyles`](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.Element#method-updateStyles) to change the style of a `Polymer.Element`.

Use `Polymer.updateStyles` to apply a change globally:

```
Polymer.updateStyles({
    '--property-one': 'var(--paper-red-900)', 
    '--property-two': 'var(--paper-indigo-500)', 
    ...
    '--property-whatever': 'etc'
})
```